# Error loading the correct version of the tex file

Tags: tcolorbox, block

I got the following error message while using a custom block environment in my document.

> ! Package tcolorbox Error: tcolorbox version '3.40' loads library
>   'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' with version '3.04'.See the tcolorbox
>   package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate
>   help.... \tcb@set@library@version{3.04}

How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried updating your packages?

Comment: I cannot update my packages as libraries are blocked in this network. So, I manually download each package whenever needed.

Comment: To install or copy locally a new version of `tcolorbox`, it is important to copy not only `tcolorbox.sty`, but all `*.code.tex` files (these contain the libraries). Otherwise, your local package will load old libraries from the system (this happens in your case).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from documentation files, the `tcolorbox` package consists of following files:

- `tcolorbox.sty` (main style file)
- `*.code.tex` (closely bound library files)

The libraries are closely bound to the corresponding main style file. Updating the main style file without updating the library files can generate a plethora of tricky errors. Therefore, the package uses a version check mechanism to ensure that the correct libraries are loaded.

> For the incidental reader: The following only applies to **manual**
>   installations. Updates via TeX-Live or MiKTeX are doing all the
>   following automatically.

The error message of the question is a result of this version check. Here, the `tcolorbox.sty` was updated locally to version `3.40`, but obviously without the corresponding library files. In this case, the old library files from the TeX system are loaded.

This solution is to copy all `*.code.tex` files together with `tcolorbox.sty` into the local directory or local installation path.

All files are found in http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox

The even better way is to download http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox.tds.zip, because here you find all installation files sorted in the `tex\latex\tcolorbox` path.

Comment: @thomas-f-sturm Is there a solution to include these `*.code.tex` files in the `\usepackage{../tcolorbox/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox}` for local developments on the package ?

Comment: @3isenHeim Yes, there is. You can use `\def\tcbpkgprefix{../wherever/} \usepackage{\tcbpkgprefix tcolorbox}`. This is **undocumented** and for local development (local `*.code.tex` files are loaded). May change without announcement in future!